# how to show the data from a myqsl database in a post

Tags: plugins, mysql

im new with using wordress. I am trying to make a website that would show the data table from my mysql database. or is there any free plugin that will be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:
    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );

then use $myrows in for or foreach loop.

Reference WP wpdb class:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0):

Get record from table data which you want to show. So you get array of all data and that array  data using foreach show on your page.

Comment: This is always true but doesn't explain how to do it in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

**To Get Current User date :**

```
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
        $uname =  $current_user->user_login;
        $mylink = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM mst_customer WHERE username= '$uname' ", ARRAY_A);
     and then print like this
    echo $current_user->user_email;
```

**To Get Particular user Recod using where condition :**

```
     global $wpdb;
     $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 1', OBJECT );
```

**or you can use :**

```
          $wpdb->query('query');
```

for more info visit this [Talking with Database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)